# Strange problem publishing a fresh Ruby on Rails 3 application on localhost (Apache, Passenger and VirtualHosts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, localhost

I recently created a new Ruby on Rails 3 application locally on a Mac OS, named "test".

Since I use apache2, in the private/etc/apache2/**httpd.conf** I set the VirtualHost for the "test" application:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.pjtmain.localhost:443
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/test/public"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/test/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.pjtmain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/test/public"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/test/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course I restart apache2, but trying to access to `http://test.pjtmain.localhost/` I have this error message from:

FIREFOX

```
Oops! Firefox could not find test.pjtmain.localhost
Suggestions:

    *
      Search on Google:
      ...
```

SAFARI

```
Safari can’t find the server.
Safari can’t open the page “http://test.pjtmain.localhost/” because Safari can’t find the server “test.pjtmain.localhost”.
```

*I have other RoR3 applications setted like that above in the httpd.conf file and all them work.*

**What is the problem (maybe it is not related to apache...)?**

*Notes*:

`1.` Using the 'Network Uility'

I did a *Ping* with the following result:

```
ping: cannot resolve test.pjtmain.localhost: Unknown host
```

and I did a *Lookup* with the follonwing result:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> test.pjtmain.localhost +multiline +nocomments +nocmd +noquestion +nostats +search
;; global options: +cmd
<MY_ISP_NAME>.com.  115 IN SOA dns1.<MY_ISP_NAME>.com. dnsmaster.<MY_ISP_NAME>.com. (
    2010110500 ; serial
    10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
    900        ; retry (15 minutes)
    604800     ; expire (1 week)
    86400      ; minimum (1 day)
    )
```

`2.` In /private/etc/hosts I have this code:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

`3.` I am using Phusion Passenger

`4.` Since I not changed nothing to the new "test" application, I expect to see the default RoR index.html page:

[image]

`5.` It seems that in the 'Console Messages' there is any warning or error

`6.` After run 'dscacheutil -flushcache', the 'dscacheutil -statistics' response is:

```
Overall Statistics:
    Average Call Time     - 0.000304
    Cache Hits            - 5311
    Cache Misses          - 6113
    Total External Calls  - 5654

Statistics by procedure:

             Procedure   Cache Hits   Cache Misses   External Calls
    ------------------   ----------   ------------   --------------
              getpwnam         1496            149             1645
              getpwuid          749             11              760
              getgrnam          157             28              185
              getgrgid           76              7               83
         getservbyname         2818             15               26
         getservbyport            0              3                3
        getprotobyname            1              1                2
              getfsent            0              0                2
         gethostbyname           14           2816               13
         gethostbyaddr            0            116              116
    gethostbyname_service            0              0             2817
           _flushcache            0              0                2
```

Comment: Can you look in the Apache logs and see if it is even getting the request?

Comment: In /private/var/log/apache2: 'ssl_request_log' file is empty; 'error_log' and 'access_log' files report old values not related to 'test.pjtmain.localhost'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem like an Apache issue at all.  The problem is in your use of DNS.

`localhost` is a placeholder for the connection the machine would use to talk to itself.  It's not the root of a domain to which you can add other names (i.e. the `test.pjtmain.` part).

Your Mac probably has a name, which you can find in the Sharing section of the Preferences utility.  Let's say it's `yourmachine`.  The sharing panel will indicate that you can reach the machine at `yourmachine.local`.

Assuming you want a unique domain name for your test app, try adding a new line for your test domain to `/private/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  pjtmain.yourmachine.local
```

Unlike `yourmachine.local`, this won't automatically work from other machines on your network, but it will work for local testing.

With all that said, though, you may want to consider avoiding the whole issue during development by just running the development server directly while developing the site.  Open a terminal window, cd to the root directory of the Rails app, and run `rails server` (if it's a Rails 3 app) or `script/server` (Rails 2).  Browse to `http://localhost:3000` and you're off and running.

Comment: Yeee! It works, thanks very much. However, regarding others subdomains, I have to change all them from 'sub_domain_name.pjtmain.localhost' to 'sub_domain_name.pjtmain.local'? It is more sure? Then, I have to add '127.0.0.1 sub_domain_name.pjtmain.local' to the /private/etc/hists file?

Comment: In short, yes.  You might want to check out these Railscasts for more ideas:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development and http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3.